# Magento send Cancel email

Tags: magento-1.9, email, transactional-mail

I am using Magento 1.9. I want to send Cancel email to the particular customer.

How to send email to the customer

Comment: order cancel email right?

Comment: yes order cancel email to customer

Comment: if order cancel  admin user then send email to customer right

Comment: Yes if admin cancel order user will get the mail

Comment: What are purpose if u question as it already  exit in magento

Comment: can you please tell me how to use that

Answer (score 2):

Follow bellow steps

Step :1
app\etc\modules\Arb_Ordercancel.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Arb_Ordercancel>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Arb_Ordercancel>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Step : 2
app\code\local\Arb\Ordercancel\etc\config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Arb_Ordercancel>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Arb_Ordercancel>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <events>
            <order_cancel_after>
                <observers>
                    <order_cancel_email>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>ordercancel/observer</class>
                        <method>orderCancelAfter</method>
                    </order_cancel_email>
                </observers>
            </order_cancel_after>
    </events>
    </global>
</config>
```

Step : 3
app\code\local\Arb\Ordercancel\Model\Observer.php

```
<?php
/**
* 
*/
class Arb_Ordercancel_Model_Observer
{
    public function orderCancelAfter($observer)
    {
        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
        $notify = true;
        $comment = 'Order Cancel';
        $order->sendOrderUpdateEmail($notify, $comment);  
    }
}
```

Comment: No I didn't got any mail

Comment: event working or not?

Comment: Event is working but i din't get any mail

Comment: Pls email configuration in admin side : System -> Configuration -> Sales -> Sales Emails : Order Comments

Comment: it's already enabled

Answer (score 1):

create file in `app/etc/modules/Solsint_Cancelorder.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Solsint_Cancelorder>
      <active>true</active>
      <codePool>local</codePool>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Solsint_Cancelorder>
  </modules>
</config>
```

create file in `app/code/local/Solsint/Cancelorder/etc/config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
<Solsint_Cancelorder>
<version>0.1.0</version>
</Solsint_Cancelorder>
</modules>

<global>
 <events>
  <sales_order_save_commit_after>
        <observers>
            <sales_order_save_commit_after>
                <class>Solsint_Cancelorder_Model_Observer</class>
                <method>sendreviewEmailOnComplete</method>
            </sales_order_save_commit_after>
        </observers>
    </sales_order_save_commit_after>
</events>
</global>
</config>
```

create file in `app/code/local/Solsint/Cancelorder/Model/Observer.php`

```
class Solsint_Cancelorder_Model_Observer{


public function sendreviewEmailOnComplete($observer)
{
    $order = $observer->getOrder();
    if($order->getState() == Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_CANCELED)
    { Mage::log('working');
     $comment='';
     $orderload=Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($order->getEntityId());
     $orderload->sendOrderUpdateEmail(true, $comment);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Can you please tell me the file path

Comment: did you create any module for that?

Comment: @Kothari use #abdul code for create module and change `event` and `observer`

Comment: can you please tell me how to change that i am not familer in this

Comment: I will create a simple module and send you

Comment: updated  the answer follow it.

Comment: No i did n't got any mail @qaisar Satti

Comment: did the module listed?

Comment: ya it listed in backend

Comment: did you work on local server or live?

Comment: Live Server only

Comment: update the observer and check ur log it is working or not..

Comment: update the config.xml and observer check it..

Comment: No luck ........

Comment: log is working did you check the log?

Comment: Please tell me How to check log i am not well and good in module

Comment: go to `var/log` folder and check `system.log`. but first check you enable it from admin panel.

Comment: it's enable only. in system.log no error on this

Comment: did you change your order status to cancel?

Comment: i change order status cancel and then only check mail

Comment: check mail and also log too